# How do I save two models that require the presence of each-other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Users belong to a Guild and can create and own others.

When creating an account a `Home` guild is created for a User that functions uniquely from other guilds.

I've tried `user=User.new ==> user.home.build` but that doesn't seem to function.

I keep getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass`

```rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: guilds
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  is_home    :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  name       :string           not null
#  owner_id   :integer          not null
#  member_id  :integer          not null
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Guild < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: :User

    has_many :guild_members, class_name: :User

    # Trying here.
    def self.create_home(user) 
        home = Guild.new(is_home: true, name: user.name, owner_id: user.id ) 
    end
end


# frozen_string_literal: true

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id              :bigint           not null, primary key
#  username        :string           not null
#  digits          :integer          not null
#  email           :string
#  password_digest :string           not null
#  session_token   :string           not null
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#  home_id         :integer          not null
#

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :home, class_name: :Guild, foreign_key: :home_id

  belongs_to :guild
end
```

Comment: The `build` method only works for collections.

Answer (score 1):

The **build method syntax** is different for **has_one** and **has_many** associations.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :home, class_name: :Guild, foreign_key: :home_id
    #Let's say user has many messages
    has_many :messages

    belongs_to :guild
end
```

Syntax for has_many association:

```
user.messages.build
```

Syntax for has_one association:

```
user.build_home  # this will work

user.home.build  # this will throw error
```

Read the has_one association [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834) for more details.